# What portion of tension reduction in a racket happens through play?

Tags: tennis, equipment, badminton, racket, squash

Basically, I'm curious whether a racket that's sitting idle will lose tension as quickly as one which is being regularly played with.

The concrete sport in question is badminton, though I suspect that the same answer holds true for tennis, squash and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, an idle racket will not lose tension as quickly. Any impact sustained by a string-bed will reduce its tension. A more intense impact will reduce the tension more. Thus, the effect in badminton is weaker than in tennis, but still existent.